Proving that the set of sentences that are true using the symbols $+,<,=$ is the same over all ordered fields
I am interested in whether the set of formulas that one can prove true for a concrete ordered field using the symbols $+,<$ and $=$, depends on the field. In particular, I am interested in the set of formulas with existential prefix.

It is the same as for $\Bbb Q$: https://www.logicgroup.altervista.org/Slides/20220617Mennuni.pdf

Abraham Robinson, Complete Theories, Theorem 4.3.2. Reference found in   https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.05570   p. 11

Let $R$ be an ordered field. Then the reduct of $R$ to the language $L_{\mathrm{og}} = \{<,+\}$ is an ordered abelian group. Moreover, $R$ is divisible: Every ordered field has characteristic $0$, hence contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{N}$, and for all $r\in R$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n>0$, we have $n\cdot (n^{-1}r) = r$.
Now the theory of ordered divisible abelian groups is well-known to be complete. See, for example, Corollary 3.1.17 in Marker's book Model Theory: An Introduction. So if $R$ and $R'$ are ordered fields, then their reducts are elementarily equivalent: $R|_{L_{\mathrm{og}}}\equiv R'|_{L_{\mathrm{og}}}$.
